# Bitwise additions, xors and left rotations in Javascript using typed arrays

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, typed-arrays

I am trying to implement a specification as a learning exercise using Javascript.

For additions, it mentions the test vector:

> 0xc0a8787e + 0x9fd1161d = 0x60798e9b.

I thought about using [Javascript's array buffer/typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) for this task and came up with the following code:

```
var sumTestArray = new Int32Array(3);
sumTestArray[0] = hexToDecimal('c0a8787e');
sumTestArray[1] = hexToDecimal('9fd1161d');
sumTestArray[2] = sumTestArray[0] + sumTestArray[1];

console.log(decimalToHex(sumTestArray[2]));

function hexToDecimal(input) {
    return parseInt(input, 16);
}
function decimalToHex(input) {
    return input.toString(16);
}
```

This results in: `60798e9b` which is correct.

**Q1) The two numbers to be added will always be 32 bit according to the spec. But is this the correct way to do hexadecimal additions in Javascript? Am I risking overflowing a buffer or getting incorrect outputs if the result number is too large?**

Another test vector is the XOR of two hexadecimal numbers:

> 0xc0a8787e ⊕ 0x9fd1161d = 0x5f796e63

My code for that is the following:

```
var xorTestArray = new Int32Array(3);
xorTestArray[0] = hexToDecimal('c0a8787e');
xorTestArray[1] = hexToDecimal('9fd1161d');
xorTestArray[2] = xorTestArray[0] ^ xorTestArray[1];

console.log(decimalToHex(xorTestArray[2]));
```

This produces the correct output of `5f796e63`

**Q2) Any risk of incorrect calculations or overflows doing that with these 32 bit typed arrays?**

The last test vector requires an n-bit left rotation with the following test vector:

`0xc0a8787e <<< 5 = 0x150f0fd8`

My code to do that was:

```
var rotateLeftTestArray = new Int32Array(2);
rotateLeftTestArray[0] = hexToDecimal('c0a8787e');
rotateLeftTestArray[1] = rotateLeftTestArray[0] << 5;

console.log(decimalToHex(rotateLeftTestArray[1]));
```

This produces `150f0fc0` which is *very close* to a match, but the last two hex characters are different and should be actually `d8` not `c0` according to the spec.

**Q3) How do I do a left bit rotation using these typed arrays to get the correct result?**

Of course, feel free to tell me if I'm doing it all wrong and shouldn't be using typed arrays for this task at all!

Comment: Just to note, you get the same sort of results, but you can specify numbers in he in javascript directly without needing a typed array, e.g. `console.log((0xc0a8787e + 0x9fd1161d).toString(16));`

Comment: `<<` does not do a rotation in JavaScript, it just does a shift.

Comment: ...to do the rotation, you need to *or* the result of the complimentary shifts: `(0xc0a8787e << 5 | (0xc0a8787e >>> (32-5))).toString(16)`

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Oh awesome that fixes the rotation, thank you! Not sure *why* that works though?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski Sorry, why do we need to 'or the result of the complimentary shifts'? What's happening at the bit level when we do that.

Comment: @Rhumborl, no that doesn't work. Your suggestion results in `160798e9b` and the correct result is `60798e9b`. Why is the extra `1` on the front of your result? What is it about the typed array that gives the correct result?

Comment: @Logice I did notice that, which is why I didn't put it as an answer, just noted the fact you can use hex. But looking again now, converting to decimal and back in a calculator gives me `3232266366 + 2681280029 = 5913546395 => 0x160798E9B`. And `0x60798e9b => 1618579099`

Comment: OK I found an [article online](https://cryptojedi.org/papers/caced25-20110211.pdf) (p.71) with the same calculation, you need to `mod 2^32` the result. This works with hex: `console.log(((0xc0a8787e + 0x9fd1161d) % Math.pow(2, 32)).toString(16));`. Don't know why the typed array version doesnt require the modulus

Comment: These are bitwise operations, I would not be tempted to use arithmetic operators, at the risk of having the result automatically converted to a different type.  The reason you have to modulus the result is that you have overflowed the 32-bit representation of the value.  The [ECMA-Script (JavaScript) specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) says the result of bitwise operations is a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Just found that I need to use Uint32Array or it fails in other test vectors of the spec with different numbers... Uint32Array passing everything though.

Comment: Since there is no rotate bits operation in JavaScript, the overflow bits are discarded and the least-significant bits are all zeroes.  Rotation means instead of discarding the shifted bits, re-introduce them at the other end of the bit pattern (instead of 'inserting zeroes').  This is why the discarded bits need to be _ored_ with the result of shifting, to simulate bit rotation.

Comment: Yes, if you're going to use arithmetic operators instead of bitwise ones, they will not return 32-bit values.

Comment: Although you can convert any integer to 32 bit by simply oring it with zero: `((0xc0a8787e + 0x9fd1161d) | 0).toString(16)`

Comment: Thanks @LeeKowalkowski it is making a bit more sense now. The spec says "A word is an element of {0, 1, ..., 2^32 − 1}. Words in this document are often written in hexadecimal, indicated by the symbols 0x: for example, 0xc0a8787e = 3232266366". I am guessing this means everything should be an unsigned integer if converted to decimal, yes? If you don't recommend arithmetic operators, what is the best way to do bitwise additions, XORs, left rotations on the hexadecimal strings? Or are arithmetic operators totally fine, I just need to convert them back to 32 bit after each operation, yes?

Comment: `+` is arithmetical, of course if you need to add two numbers together, there's no alternative.  Sometimes you see `* 2` instead of `<< 1`, but the operations will handle overflow differently.